# Use of undefined constant roll_no - assumed 'roll_no' in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am learning CodeIgniter, following this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/working_with_database.htm
facing the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Use of undefined constant roll_no - assumed 'roll_no'
>
> Filename: views/Stud_edit.php
>
> Line Number: 16
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\CI-1\application\views\Stud_edit.php
>   Line: 16
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\CI-1\application\controllers\Stud_controller.php
>   Line: 44
>   Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\CI-1\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

here my code "Stud_edit.php"

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html lang = "en">
<head> 
  <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
  <title>Students Example</title> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
  <form method = "" action = "">

     <?php 
        echo form_open('Stud_controller/update_student'); 
        echo form_hidden('old_roll_no',$old_roll_no); 
        echo form_label('Roll No.'); 
        echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no','name'=>'roll_no','value'=>$records[0]>roll_no));
        echo "<br/>"; 

        echo form_label('Name'); 
        echo form_input(array('id'=>'name','name'=>'name','value'=>$records[0]->name));
        echo "<br/>"; 

        echo form_submit(array('id'=>'submit','value'=>'Edit')); 
        echo form_close();
     ?> 

  </form>
```

Stud_controller.php

```
<?php 
  class Stud_controller extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() { 
     parent::__construct(); 
     $this->load->helper('url'); 
     $this->load->database(); 
  } 

  public function index() { 
     $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 

     $this->load->helper('url'); 
     $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
  } 

  public function add_student_view() { 
     $this->load->helper('form'); 
     $this->load->view('Stud_add'); 
  } 

  public function add_student() { 
     $this->load->model('Stud_Model');

     $data = array( 
        'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'), 
        'name' => $this->input->post('name') 
     ); 

     $this->Stud_Model->insert($data); 

     $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
  } 

  public function update_student_view() { 
     $this->load->helper('form'); 
     $roll_no = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
     $query = $this->db->get_where("stud",array("roll_no"=>$roll_no));
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $data['old_roll_no'] = $roll_no; 
     $this->load->view('Stud_edit',$data); 
  } 

  public function update_student(){ 
     $this->load->model('Stud_Model');

     $data = array( 
        'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'), 
        'name' => $this->input->post('name') 
     ); 

     $old_roll_no = $this->input->post('old_roll_no'); 
     $this->Stud_Model->update($data,$old_roll_no); 

     $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
  } 

  public function delete_student() { 
     $this->load->model('Stud_Model'); 
     $roll_no = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
     $this->Stud_Model->delete($roll_no); 

     $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
  } 
} ?>
```

Comment: couldn't get? where it is?

Comment: Read error `Line Number: 16`

Comment: do you say, -> instead of => in this line?                      echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no','name'=>'roll_no'));

Comment: `$records[0]>roll_no`

Comment: @u_mulder thanks, echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no','name'=>'roll_no','value'=>$records[0]->roll_no)); this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax has an error..

`echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no','name'=>'roll_no','value'=>$records[0]>roll_no));`

missing `-` in `$records[0]>roll_no`..

`echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no','name'=>'roll_no','value'=>$records[0]->roll_no));`